# Error: internal error: real output not found

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

When trying to create a transfer I was given the following output:

```
Error: internal error: real output not found
```

Changing the amount transfered doesn't seem to help. Trying a sweep_all does seem to work (I didn't actually submit the transfer but it at least seemed to create the transaction ok as the inputs used were displayed). Any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a remote node ?

Comment: Local monerod that is reporting synced.

Comment: Please capture a wallet log with log level 2, and file a bug on https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like its just me being silly.

The command I typed was:

```
transfer 0 REDACTED_ADDRESS_HERE DECIMAL_DIGIT_AMOUNT
```

Thinking that 0 would be the lowest priority. The correct command I should have typed is as follows:

```
transfer unimportant REDACTED_ADDRESS_HERE DECIMAL_DIGIT_AMOUNT
```